# XML::Twig replace string in a file if attribute of parent tag is something

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have an XML file: uml.model

```
<UML:Class name="2012">
  <type2>
    <type1>
        <def value="test string ABC" />
    </type1>
  </type2>
</UML:Class>

<UML:Class name="2013">
  <type2>
    <type1>
        <def value="test string ABC" />
    </type1>
  </type2>
</UML:Class>
```

I want to replace the ABC in 'UML:Class name="2012"' into DEF and have the result to be output in a new file:

```
<UML:Class name="2012">
  <type2>
    <type1>
        <def value="test string DEF" />
    </type1>
  </type2>
</UML:Class>

<UML:Class name="2013">
  <type2>
    <type1>
        <def value="test string ABC" />
    </type1>
  </type2>
</UML:Class>
```

The perl script I use is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
my $twig = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'UML:Class' => \&uml_class } );
$twig->parsefile( 'uml.model' );
$twig->print_to_file( 'uml.model.new' );

sub uml_class {
    my ( $twig, $section ) = @_;
    my $subTwig;
    my $year = $section->{'att'}->{'name'};

    if ( $year eq '2012' ) {
        $subTwig = XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'type1/def' => \&type_def } );
        $subTwig->parse( $section->sprint() };
    }
}

sub type_def {
    my ($twig, $elt) = @_;
    $elt->print ();
    print "\n";
}
```

It doesn't work as expected. How can I change it to get the desired result? Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing `print` and `print_to_file`. `print_to_file` is not magical, it doesn't cause all `print`s to go to the file. You need to modify the attribute value in the original document, then `print_to_file` will output the new value.

I would do this this way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
```

open( my $out, '>', 'uml.model.new') or die "cannot create uml.model.new: $!";

```
XML::Twig->new( twig_roots => { 'UML:Class[@name="2012"]' =>
                                   sub { my $def= $_->next_elt( 'def');
                                         $def->latt( 'value')=~ s{ABC}{DEF};
                                         $_->flush;
                                       },
                                 },
                twig_print_outside_roots => $out,
                pretty_print => 'indented',


              )
         ->parsefile( 'uml.model');
```

A couple of notes:

- I used a complex trigger (`'UML:Class[@name="2012"]'`) instead of a simple `UML:CLASS` and then testing the attribute value in the handler.
- the `latt` method gives you an attribute as an `lvalue` that you can change in place, you could alternatively use `$v= $def->att( 'value'); $v=~ s{ABC}{DEF}; $def->set_att( $v);`... but using `latt` makes it much simpler
- I chained the method calls (`new`/`parse`/`print_to_file`), I like this style for code that's as simple as this one YMMV

Comment: Michel, thanks for the quick reply. Your method works for a small snippet of the xml file. However, when use it on a big file (50M) with line over 8000 characters, the result is unexpected. None of the strings get replaced in new file (the output is a copy of original file with some attributes got replaced on the 1st line). Is there a way to debug?

Comment: I updated my answer so it would work better with big files: the tree is built only for the appropriate UML:Class elements, the rest is just output asis

Comment: debugging is done the same way you'd debug any other code: you can use the debugger, and place breakpoints inside the handler, add warn/prints inside the handler...

Comment: The XML is encoded with utf8, and there are html tags in the element. I.e.: <definition value="&#xA;&lt;x:div class=&quot; test string DEF here" />.     So I added :utf8 in open subroutine. However, the flush seems to have converted the html. So in the output, only the first line gets converted...

Comment: Also, is there a solution to keep some control characters such as "^M" (Windows) when processing it on Linux? Thanks a lot,

Comment: you're right, you need to open the output file with `:utf8` I am not sure about the "the flush seems to have converted the html" and "only the first line gets converted", you would need to give an example of the input and output.

Comment: The control characters I don't know, it could be that the parser (`expat`) converts them even before Perl sees the string. You can try using the `keep_encoding` option, but know that it's an evil hack that dates back to a pre-utf8 World and that it can lead to annoying bugs (I would guess that you would need to open the output filehandle as `:raw`, but I have very little experience processing windows files on Linux, for which I thank the appropriate deity ;--)